# how to associate file with my app

Tags: android

Hello I found solution here how to assotiate file extension with my app. My manifest look

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.micha.aa">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ur"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CurrentItem"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Saving file look

```
if(!readWrite() || readOnly()){
                    Dialog dial=new MyDialog(this,getString(R.string.error1));
                    dial.show();
                }else {

                    File toShareFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(),"temp.ur");
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = outputStream = new FileOutputStream(toShareFile);
                        ObjectOutputStream data = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
                        data.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        saved=true;

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Dialog dial=new MyDialog(this,e.getMessage());
                        dial.show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

When I open my file browser on s7 edge and tap on my file I get an error 
"Cannot open the file, your mobile phone does not have app to open it."

I have read that this fragment should work

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ur"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: At best, that `<intent-filter>` will work for an app that uses a `file` `Uri` to try to view the file. On Android 7.0+, usually the `Uri` will be a `content` `Uri`, and its path will not necessarily end in `.ur`.

Comment: so how should I change pathPattern to be able to open my file with extension .ur

Comment: That is not possible. Again, a `content` `Uri` does not need to end in any particular file extension, such as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634414/how-to-associate-file-with-my-app` does not end in `.html`. Focus instead on your app pulling in content, by offering users an "open" option from inside your app, using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and/or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: so how for example samsung in their memo app have this assotiated that if you save your memo in external memory with extension .memo and you click on it the app memo will open this file

Comment: If whatever "you click on it in the app" means uses `ACTION_VIEW` with a `file` `Intent`, then they presumably have an `<intent-filter>` that resembles yours. If whatever "you click on it in the app" means uses `ACTION_VIEW` with a `content` `Intent`, then either whatever "you click it on the app" means added a MIME type that the `<intent-filter>` uses, or Samsung modified `MimeTypeMap` on their devices for their particular MIME type. If you develop your own line of phones, you can do the same thing. Otherwise, client apps will not know a particular MIME type to use for your content.

Comment: At minimum, you need to add `<data android:scheme="content"/>` to your `<intent-filter>`. This *might* work for some `content` `Uri` values, where the creator of the `Uri` happened to keep your file extension. Just do not expect it to work everywhere.

Comment: So the best option is add button to open file in my app and then user will choose file with my extension and then I open this file?

Comment: Yes, bearing in mind that you cannot restrict the content selection to only things ending in `.ur`, and the `Uri` that you get back will not end in `.ur`, so you need to use suitable defensive programming to ensure that you handle the case where the user selects something other than what you expect.